# Laravel Yajra Datatables Individual Column Search Doesn't Work

Tags: php, laravel, yajra-datatable

In my previous code, I could use datatable with client side processing with such query:

```
Penulis::all();
```

but since there are huge amount of data exist, the load time is so long. so, I tried to use server side processing. here's my code:

The Table

```
<div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-striped" id="table_penulis">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>No</th>
                    <th>Aksi</th>
                    <th>namadepan</th>
                    <th>namatengah</th>
                    <th>namabelakang</th>
                    <th>gelardepan</th>
                    <th>gelarbelakang</th>
                    <th>jeniskelamin</th>
                    <th>tempatlahir</th>
                    <th>tanggallahir</th>
                    <th>jalan</th>
                    <th>kelurahan</th>
                    <th>rt</th>
                    <th>rw</th>
                    <th>kecamatan</th>
                    <th>kota</th>
                    <th>provinsi</th>
                    <th>kodepos</th>
                    <th>telp</th>
                    <th>email</th>
                    <th>bank</th>
                    <th>norek</th>
                    <th>namarek</th>
                    <th>pendidikanterakhir</th>
                    <th>pekerjaan</th>
                    <th>jabatan</th>
                    <th>namaperusahaan</th>
                    <th>jabatanfungsional</th>
                    <th>jabatanstruktural</th>
                    <th>prodi</th>
                    <th>jurusan</th>
                    <th>fakultas</th>
                    <th>linkedin</th>
                    <th>facebook</th>
                    <th>instagram</th>
                    <th>tiktok</th>
                    <th>namasaksi1</th>
                    <th>emailsaksi1</th>
                    <th>telpsaksi1</th>
                    <th>namasaksi2</th>
                    <th>emailsaksi2</th>
                    <th>telpsaksi2</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th class="th">namadepan</th>
                    <th class="th">namatengah</th>
                    <th class="th">namabelakang</th>
                    <th class="th">gelardepan</th>
                    <th class="th">gelarbelakang</th>
                    <th class="th">jeniskelamin</th>
                    <th class="th">tempatlahir</th>
                    <th class="th">tanggallahir</th>
                    <th class="th">jalan</th>
                    <th class="th">kelurahan</th>
                    <th class="th">rt</th>
                    <th class="th">rw</th>
                    <th class="th">kecamatan</th>
                    <th class="th">kota</th>
                    <th class="th">provinsi</th>
                    <th class="th">kodepos</th>
                    <th class="th">telp</th>
                    <th class="th">email</th>
                    <th class="th">bank</th>
                    <th class="th">norek</th>
                    <th class="th">namarek</th>
                    <th class="th">pendidikanterakhir</th>
                    <th class="th">pekerjaan</th>
                    <th class="th">jabatan</th>
                    <th class="th">namaperusahaan</th>
                    <th class="th">jabatanfungsional</th>
                    <th class="th">jabatanstruktural</th>
                    <th class="th">prodi</th>
                    <th class="th">jurusan</th>
                    <th class="th">fakultas</th>
                    <th class="th">linkedin</th>
                    <th class="th">facebook</th>
                    <th class="th">instagram</th>
                    <th class="th">tiktok</th>
                    <th class="th">namasaksi1</th>
                    <th class="th">emailsaksi1</th>
                    <th class="th">telpsaksi1</th>
                    <th class="th">namasaksi2</th>
                    <th class="th">emailsaksi2</th>
                    <th class="th">telpsaksi2</th>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
            <tbody></tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

the Datatable (JQuery)

```
$('#table_penulis').DataTable({
        processing  : true,
        serverSide  : true,
        responsive  : true,
        dom         : 'Bfrtip',
        paging      : true,
        ajax: "/api/master-penulis-datatable",
        columns: [
            {data  : 'DT_RowIndex',        name  : 'DT_RowIndex', orderable: false, searchable: false},
            {data  : 'action',             name  : 'action',      orderable: false, searchable: false},
            {data  : 'namadepan',          name  : 'namadepan'                                       },
            {data  : 'namatengah',         name  : 'namatengah'                                      },
            {data  : 'namabelakang',       name  : 'namabelakang'                                    },
            {data  : 'gelardepan',         name  : 'gelardepan'                                      },
            {data  : 'gelarbelakang',      name  : 'gelarbelakang'                                   },
            {data  : 'jeniskelamin',       name  : 'jeniskelamin'                                    },
            {data  : 'tempatlahir',        name  : 'tempatlahir'                                     },
            {data  : 'tanggallahir',       name  : 'tanggallahir'                                    },
            {data  : 'jalan',              name  : 'jalan'                                           },
            {data  : 'kelurahan',          name  : 'kelurahan'                                       },
            {data  : 'rt',                 name  : 'rt'                                              },
            {data  : 'rw',                 name  : 'rw'                                              },
            {data  : 'kecamatan',          name  : 'kecamatan'                                       },
            {data  : 'kota',               name  : 'kota'                                            },
            {data  : 'provinsi',           name  : 'provinsi'                                        },
            {data  : 'kodepos',            name  : 'kodepos'                                         },
            {data  : 'telp',               name  : 'telp'                                            },
            {data  : 'email',              name  : 'email'                                           },
            {data  : 'bank',               name  : 'bank'                                            },
            {data  : 'norek',              name  : 'norek'                                           },
            {data  : 'namarek',            name  : 'namarek'                                         },
            {data  : 'pendidikanterakhir', name  : 'pendidikanterakhir'                              },
            {data  : 'pekerjaan',          name  : 'pekerjaan'                                       },
            {data  : 'jabatan',            name  : 'jabatan'                                         },
            {data  : 'namaperusahaan',     name  : 'namaperusahaan'                                  },
            {data  : 'jabatanfungsional',  name  : 'jabatanfungsional'                               },
            {data  : 'jabatanstruktural',  name  : 'jabatanstruktural'                               },
            {data  : 'prodi',              name  : 'prodi'                                           },
            {data  : 'jurusan',            name  : 'jurusan'                                         },
            {data  : 'fakultas',           name  : 'fakultas'                                        },
            {data  : 'linkedin',           name  : 'linkedin'                                        },
            {data  : 'facebook',           name  : 'facebook'                                        },
            {data  : 'instagram',          name  : 'instagram'                                       },
            {data  : 'tiktok',             name  : 'tiktok'                                          },
            {data  : 'namasaksi1',         name  : 'namasaksi1'                                      },
            {data  : 'emailsaksi1',        name  : 'emailsaksi1'                                     },
            {data  : 'telpsaksi1',         name  : 'telpsaksi1'                                      },
            {data  : 'namasaksi2',         name  : 'namasaksi2'                                      },
            {data  : 'emailsaksi2',        name  : 'emailsaksi2'                                     },
            {data  : 'telpsaksi2',         name  : 'telpsaksi2'                                      },
        ],
        initComplete: function() {
            this.api().columns().every(function() {
                var that = this;

                $('input', this.footer()).on('keyup change clear', function() {
                    if (that.search() !== this.value) {
                        that.search(this.value).draw();
                    }
                });

                $('#table_penulis tfoot .th').each(function() {
                    var title = $(this).text();
                    $(this).html('<input type="text" class="form-control rounded shadow" placeholder="search" />');
                });
            });
        },
    });
```

and here's the Controller

```
$data  = Penulis::query();
    return $dataTables->eloquent($data)
            ->addIndexColumn()
            ->addColumn('action', function($row){
                $btn = '<btn class="btn btn-info btn-sm" data-id="'. $row->id .'"><i class="bi bi-eye text-white"></i></btn>';
                return $btn;
            })
            ->rawColumns(['action'])
            ->toJson();
```

I'm using postgresql, here's the DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE "royalti"."writers" (
"namadepan" VARCHAR ( 50 ) COLLATE "pg_catalog"."default",
"namatengah" VARCHAR ( 50 ) COLLATE "pg_catalog"."default",
"namabelakang" VARCHAR ( 50 ) COLLATE "pg_catalog"."default",
"gelardepan" VARCHAR ( 20 ) COLLATE "pg_catalog"."default",
"gelarbelakang" VARCHAR ( 50 ) COLLATE "pg_catalog"."default",
"jeniskelamin" CHAR ( 1 ) COLLATE "pg_catalog"."default",
"tempatlahir" VARCHAR ( 100 ) COLLATE "pg_catalog"."default",
"tanggallahir" DATE,
"jalan" VARCHAR ( 255 ) COLLATE "pg_catalog"."default",
"kelurahan" VARCHAR ( 100 ) COLLATE "pg_catalog"."default",
"rt" VARCHAR ( 10 ) COLLATE "pg_catalog"."default",
"rw" VARCHAR ( 10 ) COLLATE "pg_catalog"."default",
"kecamatan" VARCHAR ( 100 ) COLLATE "pg_catalog"."default",
"kota" VARCHAR ( 100 ) COLLATE "pg_catalog"."default",
"provinsi" VARCHAR ( 100 ) COLLATE "pg_catalog"."default",
"kodepos" VARCHAR ( 10 ) COLLATE "pg_catalog"."default",
"telp" VARCHAR ( 20 ) COLLATE "pg_catalog"."default",
"email" VARCHAR ( 100 ) COLLATE "pg_catalog"."default",
"norek" VARCHAR ( 20 ) COLLATE "pg_catalog"."default",
"namarek" VARCHAR ( 100 ) COLLATE "pg_catalog"."default",
"pendidikanterakhir" VARCHAR ( 10 ) COLLATE "pg_catalog"."default",
"pekerjaan" VARCHAR ( 100 ) COLLATE "pg_catalog"."default",
"jabatan" VARCHAR ( 100 ) COLLATE "pg_catalog"."default",
"namaperusahaan" VARCHAR ( 100 ) COLLATE "pg_catalog"."default",
"jabatanfungsional" VARCHAR ( 100 ) COLLATE "pg_catalog"."default",
"jabatanstruktural" VARCHAR ( 100 ) COLLATE "pg_catalog"."default",
"prodi" VARCHAR ( 100 ) COLLATE "pg_catalog"."default",
"jurusan" VARCHAR ( 100 ) COLLATE "pg_catalog"."default",
"fakultas" VARCHAR ( 100 ) COLLATE "pg_catalog"."default",
"linkedin" VARCHAR ( 100 ) COLLATE "pg_catalog"."default",
"facebook" VARCHAR ( 100 ) COLLATE "pg_catalog"."default",
"instagram" VARCHAR ( 100 ) COLLATE "pg_catalog"."default",
"tiktok" VARCHAR ( 100 ) COLLATE "pg_catalog"."default",
"namasaksi1" VARCHAR ( 255 ) COLLATE "pg_catalog"."default",
"emailsaksi1" VARCHAR ( 100 ) COLLATE "pg_catalog"."default",
"telpsaksi1" VARCHAR ( 20 ) COLLATE "pg_catalog"."default",
"namasaksi2" VARCHAR ( 255 ) COLLATE "pg_catalog"."default",
"emailsaksi2" VARCHAR ( 100 ) COLLATE "pg_catalog"."default",
"telpsaksi2" VARCHAR ( 20 ) COLLATE "pg_catalog"."default",
"id" INT8 NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY ( INCREMENT 1 MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807 START 1 CACHE 1 ),
"bank" VARCHAR ( 100 ) COLLATE "pg_catalog"."default",
CONSTRAINT "writers_pkey" PRIMARY KEY ( "id" ));
ALTER TABLE "royalti"."writers" OWNER TO "postgres";
```

The Client Side can perform individual column search, but since I'm using this type of serverside, the search doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Changed my Datatable JQuery to :

```
$(function() {
        var table = $('#table_penulis').DataTable({
            responsive: true,
            dom: 'Bfrtip',
            processing: true,
            serverSide: true,
            paginf: true,
            ajax: '/api/master-penulis-datatable',
            columns: [
                {data: 'DT_RowIndex', name: 'DT_RowIndex', orderable: false, searchable: false},
                {data: 'action', name: 'action', orderable: false, searchable: false},
                {data: 'nama', name: 'nama'},
                {data: 'jeniskelamin', name: 'jeniskelamin'},
                {data: 'tempatlahir', name: 'tempatlahir'},
                {data: 'tanggallahir', name: 'tanggallahir'},
                {data: 'jalan', name: 'jalan'},
                {data: 'kelurahan', name: 'kelurahan'},
                {data: 'rt', name: 'rt'},
                {data: 'rw', name: 'rw'},
                {data: 'kecamatan', name: 'kecamatan'},
                {data: 'kota', name: 'kota'},
                {data: 'provinsi', name: 'provinsi'},
                {data: 'kodepos', name: 'kodepos'},
                {data: 'telp', name: 'telp'},
                {data: 'email', name: 'email'},
                {data: 'bank', name: 'bank'},
                {data: 'norek', name: 'norek'},
                {data: 'namarek', name: 'namarek'},
                {data: 'pendidikanterakhir', name: 'pendidikanterakhir'},
                {data: 'pekerjaan', name: 'pekerjaan'},
                {data: 'jabatan', name: 'jabatan'},
                {data: 'namaperusahaan', name: 'namaperusahaan'},
                {data: 'jabatanfungsional', name: 'jabatanfungsional'},
                {data: 'jabatanstruktural', name: 'jabatanstruktural'},
                {data: 'prodi', name: 'prodi'},
                {data: 'jurusan', name: 'jurusan'},
                {data: 'fakultas', name: 'fakultas'},
                {data: 'linkedin', name: 'linkedin'},
                {data: 'facebook', name: 'facebook'},
                {data: 'instagram', name: 'instagram'},
                {data: 'tiktok', name: 'tiktok'},
                {data: 'namasaksi1', name: 'namasaksi1'},
                {data: 'emailsaksi1', name: 'emailsaksi1'},
                {data: 'telpsaksi1', name: 'telpsaksi1'},
                {data: 'namasaksi2', name: 'namasaksi2'},
                {data: 'emailsaksi2', name: 'emailsaksi2'},
                {data: 'telpsaksi2', name: 'telpsaksi2'},
            ],
            initComplete: function() {
                this.api()
                    .columns()
                    .every(function() {
                        var that = this;
                        $('input', this.footer()).on('keyup change clear', function() {
                            if (that.search() !== this.value) {
                                that.search(this.value).draw();
                            }
                        });
                    });
            }
        });

        $('#table_penulis tfoot .th').each(function() {
            var title = $(this).text();
            $(this).html('<input type="text" class="form-control shadow" placeholder="search" />');
        });
    });
```